# What is the Impact of Changing parameters like “autocreate = true" in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

And   `generate="true"`  etc.
On  Type  System  etc.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at product documentation?

Answer (score 7):

`autocreate` is true by default and setting this modifier in a type means that the item will be created during initialization.
`generate` is also true by default and depending on where it's placed can mean different things:

- In an `atomictypeType`, `collectiontypeType`, `maptypeType`, `relationType`: Deprecated, has no effect
- In an `attributeModelType`, `attributeType`: If set as true, getters and setters will be created for the attribute when the project is compiled
- In an `enumtypeType`: If *false* no constants will be generated at constant class of extension as well as at corresponding servicelayer enum class
- In an `itemModelType`, `itemtypeType`: Whether a model for the type and models for subtypes will be generated

Comment: Thanks  Juan for  this  Lucid  illustration.  Are there any other parameters that impact item Creation

Comment: You can find the full reference guide in the hybris page. Also, if the question helped you, could you accept it or upvote it? Thanks

Comment: juan,  i am afraid i didn't find this functionality  of  Accepting / Upvoating  on  this site.

Answer (score 5):

***Autocreate -***

> autocreate is true, which lets the hybris Commerce Suite to create a
>   new database entry for this type at initialization/update process.
>   Setting the autocreate modifier to false causes a build failure. The
>   first definition of a type has to enable this flag.

***Generate -***

> *Jalo Layer:* Setting the generate modifier to true results in Java class files being generated for this type [Additional
>   Details](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Type+System+Documentation#TypeSystemDocumentation-abstractclasses).
>   Setting the generate modifier to false results in no Java class file
>   being generated for this type. Having no Java class file available
>   means that you are not able to implement a custom business logic (such
>   as getter and / or setter methods) for the type. You have to make use
>   of the supertype's business logic implementation.

Answer (score 2):

***autocreate=true*** at the item type level
 - It hints hybris to create a new database entry for this type at initialization/update process
If we set it to false,build will fail.
We should set it to true for the first definition of item type.

***generate=true*** at the item type level
 - It hints hybris to generate a new jalo class for this type during build time.
If we set it to false,then jalo class will not be generated however model class will always be generated.
We should set it to true for the first definition of item type.